# How do I confirm that Eigen is enabling vectorization in Visual Studios? How do check to see that EIGEN_VECTORIZE preprocessor symbol is defined?

Tags: visual-studio, vectorization, eigen

I was attempting to get Eigen working with some code in Visual Studios 2019 using Visual Studios 2015 build tools.

I would like to confirm that Eigen is detecting and enabling its vectorization.

According to [Eigen FAQ](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#How_can_I_enable_vectorization.3F), Eigen "will automatically enable its vectorization if a supported SIMD instruction set and a supported compiler are detected".

I have the "Maximize Speed" flag (/O2) turned on in *Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Optimization*

Also according to Eigen FAQ, in order to check that vectorization is being used, "First you can check that Eigen vectorization is enabled: the EIGEN_VECTORIZE preprocessor symbol is then defined."

If I look under *Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor*, I do not see  EIGEN_VECTORIZE listed.

Does this mean that it is not defined? How do I check for this preprocessor symbol?

Answer (score 0):

You don't define `EIGEN_VECTORIZE`, it gets defined in the `Eigen/Core` file. Basically, the code reads as:

```
#ifndef EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE
    #define EIGEN_VECTORIZE
    #define EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSE
    #define EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSE2
```

and continues on to check if each instruction set is being used, and if so defining `EIGEN_VECTORIZE_YYY` (where `YYY` is the instruction set). One thing to note, is that MSVC does not have definitions for  SSE greater than 2. If you want to use those instructions, you'll have to explicitly define `EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSE3`, `EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSSE3`, `EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSE4_1`, `EIGEN_VECTORIZE_SSE4_2`. I'm not sure if it defines `__FMA__` either, so you would probably want tot define `EIGEN_VECTORIZE_FMA` if you enable AVX2.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.